# why does layoutSubviews get called twice during device rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, autolayout

when i rotate device these functions got called in the exact order :

> viewWillLayoutSubviews()
>
> layoutSubviews()
>
> viewDidLayoutSubviews()
>
> viewWillLayoutSubviews()
>
> layoutSubviews()
>
> viewDidLayoutSubviews()

i was just simply rotating the device, i had simple initial default blank view controller that xcode created for me automatically, so what is the reason for app calling set of 3 layout functions for the **second** time?

code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    print(#function)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print(#function)
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide code for more details?

Comment: @Kudos updated question, + i overrode main view class method layoutSubviews to print during the invocation